# Pygame Object Is Not Subscriptable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I have been trying to make a RPG game for Python 3.X but when i try to load in a rectangle on Pygame using raspberry Pi Debian it says that:

```
File "/home/pi/Desktop/Graphics/PyGame Test1.py", line 28, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect[object,GREEN,{10,15}]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable
```

I am fairly new to using Pygame and was wondering what was wrong, the Whole code for it is,

```
import pygame, sys, time, random
from pygame.locals import*
pygame.init()
gameSurface=pygame.display.set_mode((440,480))
pygame.display.set_caption('PiBuster')
pygame.mouse.set_visible(0)
SHADOW = (192, 192, 192)

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

LIGHTGREEN = (0, 255, 0 )

GREEN = (0, 200, 0 )

BLUE = (0, 0, 128)

LIGHTBLUE= (0, 0, 255)

RED= (200, 0, 0 )

LIGHTRED= (255, 100, 100)

PURPLE = (102, 0, 102)

LIGHTPURPLE= (153, 0, 153)
gameSurface.fill(BLUE)
pygame.display.update()
pygame.draw.rect[object,GREEN,{10,15}]
```

Comment: You almost certainly want to use parentheses instead of square brackets here. In other words, you should _call_ `pygame.draw.rect`, not try to subscript it.

Comment: @ForceBru  What do you mean by 'calll' it in i have seen lots of posts about objects not being callable but mine says not subscriptable

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that `pygame.draw.rect` is a method and to give a method arguments you use parenthesis (i.e. '()') not square brackets. So try `pygame.draw.rect(object,GREEN,{10,15})`.